# Reading attachment data from a PostgreSQL table with python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, postgresql

I have developed this script to find the counts of attachment records stored in a table in PostgreSQL for different other tables. I check if the `res_id` field of `ir_attachment` table is existed in it's corresponding table `(res_model)` and if it's not existed, I increase the counter. This script works fine and I get the desired result but it is slow with big number of records (9000000 -10000000). How can I improve this script's performance to optimize it? Should I use any SQL technic or bring changes in python code?

```
def delete_attachment(self):
        self.apps_cursor.execute("""
                                SELECT id,res_id,res_model FROM ir_attachment WHERE res_model IS NOT NULL AND res_id IS NOT NULL limit 5;
                                """)
        counter = 0
        attachment_records = self.apps_cursor.fetchall()
        print '=========================================Checking attachment records started========================================='
        self.apps_cursor.execute("""
                SELECT model FROM ir_model WHERE model IS NOT NULL;
        """)
        apps_models = self.apps_cursor.fetchall()
        apps_models = [model.get('model') for model in apps_models]
        for record in attachment_records:
            if record['res_model'] in apps_models:
                model_name = str(record['res_model'].replace('.', '_'))
                self.apps_cursor.execute("""
                        SELECT id FROM %s WHERE id=%s
                """ % (model_name, record['res_id']))
                model_record = self.apps_cursor.fetchall()

                if not model_record:
                    counter += 1
        print 'Total attachment records with out res_id field existed in corresponding model:', counter
```

Comment: I would recommend writing any future python programs in `python-3.x`, as [python2.x has reached it's end of life.](https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/09/python-2-end-of-life-approaching/)

Comment: Thank you for nice suggestion, actually I did this in python 2 because of some limitation. Server not supporting python 3 and I can't run any python 3 code there.

Comment: Then I would recommend upgrading your server to python 3.